# Chrome DevTools, always reset focus in callstack

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, callstack

[image]

Latelly i dont know what combination of keys i did to do this. But even when i close the callstack in DevTools, it reopens and refocus on it, on every debug steps!

This is starting to be incredibly annoying, when stepping through code and loosing variables because of a 50 line callstack.

I tryed uninstall, clear registry, still hapenning.

Anyone have any idea how to stop this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Noticed the same annoying behaviour in the last days. Still looking for a fix.

Comment: It seems it miraculously stopped since last update. Finally!!